# Unable to convert String Representation of List to List in Python

Tags: python, json, string, list

I am trying a web application using multi-cloud platforms. I am using AWS Lambda and GCP to achieve this. However, when I am returning 2 lists from the AWS Lambda to my GAE, I am unable to traverse through the lists retrieved from Lambda. Below is the piece of code for implementing the same.

Lambda Code:

```
newvar95.append(var95)
newvar99.append(var99)
return json.dumps([newvar95,newvar99])
```

GAE Python Code:-

```
def getpage(id):
    import json
    awsC = http.client.HTTPSConnection("XXXXXX.XXXXXXXX")
    json_obj = '{"key1":"'+open1+'","key2":"'+high1+'","key3":"'+low1+'","key4":"'+close1+'","key5":"'+mini+'","key6":"'+shots+'","key7":"'+Tsignal+'"}'
    awsC.request("POST","/XXXXX/XXXXX",json_obj)
    response = awsC.getresponse()
    data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
                    res = json.loads(data)
    print(res + str(id))
                    #return(res +str(id))
    
def getpages():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results=executor.map(getpage,runs)
    return results

initial_time=time.time()
risk_analysis = getpages()
            
executiont_time=time.time()-initial_time
```

I am expecting to get something like this :

```
\[\[8.23, 4.89,9.23,9.80\],4\]
```

What I am getting is something like this :

```
"\[8.23, 4.89,9.23,9.80\],4"
```

Comment: [newvar for i in [newvar95,newvar99]] try this and see if this gets what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: it is considered bad practice to use the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function. But just for education, you can do:

```
s =  "[8.23, 4.89,9.23,9.80],4"
s = eval(f"[{s}]")
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[[8.23, 4.89, 9.23, 9.8], 4]
```

where `s` ends up with the type `list`.

In order not to use `eval()`, we can do this more complicated method *(which I will post soon)*.